# "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process" with Images

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-in-use

I've seen many issues like this that have been solved and the problem was mostly due to streams not being disposed of properly.

My issue is slightly different, here follow a code snippet

```
 foreach (Images item in ListOfImages)
 {
      newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, item.ImageName + item.ImageExtension);
      File.Create(newPath);

      File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, item.File);
 }
```

Where `Images` is a custom struct and `item.File` is the raw data, byte[].

My issue is that at the line where the `WriteAllBytes` is called, an exception is thrown. The message reads:

`The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

Again I have no clue how am I going to somehow `close` the process.

Comment: Do some of the Images have the same ImageName and ImageExtension?

Comment: Are you sure, is the path newPath exists?

Comment: delete `File.Create(newPath);` and try. File.WriteAllBytes: `Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is overwritten.` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx

Comment: You do not dispose stream created by File.Create. So it is still using that file. Tim's answer is correct

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Since `File.Create` returns the stream i would dispose it properly:

```
using(var stream = File.Create(newPath)){}
File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, item.File);
```

or you can use the stream to write to the file directly:

```
using (FileStream fs = File.Create(newPath))
{
    fs.Write(item.File, 0, item.File.Length);
}
```

or, probably the easiest, use [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) alone:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, item.File);
```

> Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and
>   then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is
>   overwritten.

Comment: This...File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, item.File); worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

You state that your problem has nothing to do with disposing streams but check this MSDN article:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx

What does `File.Create` return? A FileStream!!!!

And, at the end of the day, why are you using `File.Create` if `File.WriteAllBytes` creates a file if this doesn't exist? ;)

> Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and
>   then closes the file. If the target file already exists, it is
>   overwritten.

Check it on MSDN too: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
using (FileStream fs = 
new FileStream(filePath,
    FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
```

Your log may be write locked, so try with FileShare.ReadWrite.

Answer (score 1):

The [create method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03.aspx) opens the file for writing and returns a FileStream object for you to work with.  Just because you are not referencing it *does not* mean it does not need to be returned.

```
foreach (Images item in ListOfImages)
                {
                    newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, item.ImageName + item.ImageExtension);
                    FileStream f = File.Create(newPath);

                    f.Write(item.File, 0, item.File.Length);
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the most specific way to accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
foreach (Images item in ListOfImages)
{
    using (System.IO.FileStream output = new System.IO.FileStream(Path.Combine(newPath, item.ImageName + item.ImageExtension),
        System.IO.FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write))
    {
        output.Write(item.File, 0, item.File.Length);
        output.Flush();
        output.Close();
    }
}
```

You also need to fix your logic for creating the path, which I have done in my example above. You were concatenating the newPath over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

The `File.WriteAllBytes` creates the file if necessary. You can juts use:

```
foreach (Images item in ListOfImages)
{
    newPath = Path.Combine(newPath, item.ImageName + item.ImageExtension);
    File.WriteAllBytes(newPath, item.File);
}
```

And are you combine path correctly?

Answer (score -3):

Force the garbage collector to clean.

```
GC.Collect();
```