# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process c# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am simply trying to create a file using c# and writing in it. Here is my code:

```
public void AddLog (string message, string fn_name)
{
    string path = @"E:\" + fn_name +".txt";
    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Create(path);
        File.Delete(path);
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
        tw.WriteLine("" + message +"");
        tw.Close();
    }
    else if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path,true);
        tw.WriteLine("" + message + "");
        tw.Close();
    }
}
```

The problem is it always gives me this exception:

> {"The process cannot access the file 'E:\CheckForFriends.txt' because
>   it is being used by another process."}

at this line: `File.Delete(path);`
and even if I removed this line it gives me the same exception message at the line: `File.Create(path);`

So, anyone have an idea what is wrong in my code?

Comment: So if the file doesn't exist, you create it and then immediately delete it... why?

Comment: Seriously, what are you trying to do??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335349/the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process

Comment: @stuartd and @Viru i am trying to create a file and write in it...and even when i remove the `File.Delete(path);` still gives the same error at `TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);`

Comment: Sorry, late to the party but 'real' problem with your code is that File.Create returns a FileStream object which needs to be disposed before trying to access the same file handle again. It's not as pretty as say, wrapping it in a using statement but you can chain the Dispose method on the call and clean it up in one fell swoop. ie: File.Create(path).Dispose();

Comment: @MikeJohnson thank you...this makes sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When using disposable resources (things that implement IDisposable), you should use the using statement.

You can simplify to this, the StreamWriter will create the file if it doesn't exist.

```
public void AddLog (string message, string fn_name)
{
    string path = @"E:\" + fn_name +".txt";
    using(var tw = new StreamWriter(path, true))
    {
      tw.WriteLine(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works..Thank you

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are creating and opening a file, and trying to delete it while it is still opened:

```
      File.Create(path);
      File.Delete(path);
```

It should be just

```
public void AddLog (string message, string fn_name)
    {
        string path = @"E:\" + fn_name +".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (File.Create(path))
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path))
                tw.WriteLine("" + message +"");
        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path,true))
                tw.WriteLine("" + message + "");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much...it's clear now

Answer (score 0):

i am not sure but you are deleting the file while it is being used by some other process:

try the below code:

```
public void AddLog (string message, string fn_name)
    {
        string path = @"E:\" + fn_name +".txt";
        if (!File.Exists(path))
        {
            File.Create(path);

            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);
            tw.WriteLine("" + message +"");
            tw.Close();
            File.Delete(path);

        }
        else if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path,true);
            tw.WriteLine("" + message + "");
            tw.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I tried it still not working. It gives me the same error at: `TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(path);`